# Google App Script の htmlservice のダイアログ処理が Firefox で動作しない

Tags: google-apps-script, firefox

GASでダイアログをspread sheetに表示したいと思って以下のコードを書きました。

これをスプレッドシートで実行してみましたが、Google Chromeだと動作するがFirefoxだと動作しません。
（ダイアログが表示されないがスクリプトは正常終了する）
なぜですか？
`showModalDialog` を `showModelessDialog` にしても同じでした。

```
function showdlgtest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("newtest");
  Logger.log(html)
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Logger.log(ui)
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "sample")

}
```

newtest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。
https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/addon/google-shortcuts-all-google-se/
を入れているとspreadsheetが正常動作しないということのようです